# Counting occurrences of an array element - Index out of bounds error but the index number and out of bounds length are the same number?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

So I'm having some issues with code I'm writing for an assignment and it's kinda driving me crazy. It's my first semester and I've never done coding before, so I know I still have heaps to learn. Anyways, the issues:

I'm having two problems which could be related but I'm not 100% sure. I'm getting this error:

*'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 125 out of bounds for length 125.'*

Which points to the following section of code (Commented on specific line):

```
public static String gradesDistn() {
    String gradeDistn = "0";
    
    //Sort the above letterGrade array
    Arrays.sort(letterGrade);
    
    //This loop counts each occurrence of an element in the letterGrade array.
    for (int i = 0; i < letterGrade.length - 1; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < letterGrade.length; j++) {
            if  (letterGrade[i] == letterGrade[j]) 
                count++;
                
        System.out.println (gradeDistn = letterGrade[i] + ": " + count); //THIS IS THE ERROR LINE.
        i += (count-1);
        }
    }  
    return gradeDistn;
```

I can post the full code if additional context is needed. Essentially I'm am trying to count the occurrences of each letter grade (A, B, C, D, E and F) which are stored in an array. Each occurrence is based off of another array which stores number marks and is randomly generated. So the results should look something like this:

A: 6

B: 10

C:20

D: 9

E: 3

F: 1

instead I'm getting (copied from console):

A: 1

A: 2

A: 3

A: 4

B: 5

B: 6

B: 7

B: 8

B: 9

B: 10

B: 11

C: 11

C: 11

D: 11

D: 11

F: 11

C: 20

D: 9

E: 3

F: 1

I've spent so long looking at these code and trying to make it work, I feel like I'm am blind to the potentially obvious issues with it. Any help on this 2 issues would be really appreciated!

Also of note: The assignment requires a bunch of super specific methods such as this so that can't be changed, addition classes can not be used etc.

Comment: You do get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception thrown when the value of the index is the same as the array length.  Recall that Java indexing is zero based.  So, if you have an array of `n` elements, the valid indices are from `0` to `n - 1`.

Comment: How is `letterGrade` declared?  From your code it should be `char []`. Is it?

Comment: In general, it is considered poor style to alter the index value of a `for` loop within the block controlled by the loop, as you are in this case. For future reference, when you are in that situation, consider using a `while` or a `do ... while` loop instead.

Comment: You have a `System.out.println` statement in the inner nested loop.  That's good for debugging. But, it doesn't represent the final result. If you want to see what will be returned, add another `System.out.println` before the `return` statement or after the call to `gradeDistn`.  Make it so you can distinguish them.

Comment: By the way, does your `System.out.println` really have that `=` in it?

Comment: Comparing elements of the array with each other as `if  (letterGrade[i] == letterGrade[j]) ` does is not what you want to do if you are reporting the frequency of each letter. You need to have separate arrays of the letters and the counts.

Answer (score 0):

For this answer, I'm going to put aside the question of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and offer guidance on how to generate a frequency distribution.

You are going to want a set of counters. Each counter will represent a range of values. To start, you should decide what range each counter will represent.  Too fine a resolution, and your frequency distribution will not be very useful. For example, if your data is 100 meter sprint times for high school boys, and each counter represents an interval of 1/10,000 of a second, unless your sample size is very large, your frequency distribution would have a lot of values of '1' and '0'. You might want to separate by 1/10 of a second, 1 second, or 2 seconds, depending on how much variation there is in the boys' times.

But, if your data is species of farm animals, it would be fine to have a separate counter for each possible value.

So, determine how many counters you will need. What is the range of possible values?  How closely do you want to group them?

Next, you will want a means of linking a particular value to a particular counter. In some cases, a little math can be used. In other cases, an `if ... else if ...` chain or a `switch` block is useful.

For the first example, I want to analyze daily high temperatures. I decide to group by 10 degrees Fahrenheit. I could decide on 5 degrees, 7 degrees, or some other interval. It could even be irregular intervals. But, keeping it regular and going by 10 degrees makes the example easier to follow.

Having settled on grouping by 10 degrees, I next want to decide the maximum and minimum. I'll pick -19 as the coldest, and 119 as the hottest. But, I want to allow for occurrences outside of that range.  So, to hold the count, I will want an array of 15 counters.

Next, I will want a means of "translating" a temperature measurement to an array index. I use the `int` variable `k` for that in the following code. To make it easier to follow, I broke the calculation into 4 lines and then used the result as a subscript:

```
public static int [] tempFreqDist (WeatherStats [] daily) {
    int [] count = new int [15];  // java initializes to zeros
    int k;
    for (int dIdx = 0; dIdx < daily.length; ++ dIdx) {
          k = daily [dIdx].getHighTemp();
          k = Math.max (k,-20);
          k = Math.min (k,120);
          k = k/10 + 2;
          count [k]++;
    }    
    return count;
}
```

That's it! One loop, and no sorting.

We want to group temps of -20 and colder together, regardless of how far below -20.  So, we use `Math.max`. Similarly, we group temps of 120 and hotter by using `Math.min`. Next, divide by our grouping factor, and adjust the result so the lowest has `0` for the subscript value.

So, the result is the elements of `count` correspond to the temperature ranges:  0 ➔ -20 and colder; 1 ➔ "teens" (10 to 19) below zero; 2 ➔ single digits below zero; 3 ➔ zero and single digits above; 4 ➔ teens above zero; 5 ➔ twenties, ..., 14 ➔ teens above 100; 14 ➔ 120 and above.

But, suppose the 'width' of categories was irregular?  One possibility is that you could use a chain of `if ... else`:

```
int t = daily [dIdx].getHighTemp();
if (t <= -20) k = 0;       
else if (t <= -13) k = 1;  
else if (t <= 0) k = 2;
else if (t <= 15) k = 3;
else if (t <= 28) k = 4;
```

and so on.

Another example counts animals you might see on a farm.

You can do that with an `if ... else if ...` chain:

```
 public int[] animalFD (String [] species) {
    int [] count = new int [6]; 
      // 0 ➔ cattle, 1 ➔ pig, 2 ➔ sheep, 
      // 3 ➔ goat, 4 ➔ duck, 5 ➔ horse 
    ...
    for (int m = 0; m < species.length; ++m) {
       if (species[m].equals("cow") count[0]++;
       else if (species[m].equals("pig") count [1]++;
       else if ...
```

But, for something like this, I prefer `switch` to `if ... else` chain:

```
public static int [] animalFD (String [] species) {
    int [] count = new int [6];
    for (int m = 0; m < species.length; ++m) {
        switch (letterGrade [m]) {
            case "cow": 
                count[0]++;
                break;
            case "pig":
                count [1]++;
                break;
            case "sheep":
                count [2]++;
                break;
            case "goat":
                count [3]++;
                break;
...
```

Here is a "trick" you can use to easily convert a letter to an index.  Recall that a `char` is essentially a integer primitive: You can do numeric calculations on it.

```
 char letter;
 int idx;
 ...
 if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z') { 
    idx = letter - 'A'; // result is zero to 25
 ...
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the letters A to Z are consecutive in character set encoding. However, that isn't universal.  EBCDIC, for example, has non-letter characters between `I` and `J`, and between `R` and `S`, IIRC.

Comment: I left out showing names of the groups on the output. One way would be to  set up a corresponding array with the names or ranges of each group.